# Is there a way to get a content's parent folder url in cmis?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am working on alfresco with cmis to get a content & its parent folder. I could get content as well as its download url. Also i am able to get its parent folder path using

```
 parent.getProperty("cmis:path").getValue()
```

But along with path i also want the url to folder location where content resides such as in alfresco search.

```
 http://localhost:8080/share/page/site/demo/documentlibrary?path=%2Ftest
```

Or is there any way to get a document's container folder URL in cmis?

Can anybody help?

Regards.

Comment: Are you aware that Share is not the only possible User Interface for Alfresco, and therefore there's no "universally right answer" for "the URL"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to construct the URL manually, because CMIS is just a platform independent protocol that knows nothing about Alfresco Share & the URL-pattern that have to be used within Share.

Comment: Thanks all, i was able to do it using cmisatom based content download URL. E.g. http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom/44af2c30-d3ef-4769-bd80-f4dfc3d97d56/content/alf.jsp?id=workspace://SpacesStore/b3cbf581-78b7-4546-9d43-43995eabbb11;1.0". Idea is to use generic component http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom & adding repository id as well as noderef of the document. It worked fine.